# Почему NodeJS так долго не реализует поддержку модулей ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Не взирая на то, что спецификацию ES6 выпустили в 2015 году, даже в 2019 NodeJS всё ещё не реализует этот стандарт. Поддержка всё ещё экспериментальная и судя по описанию работает только на уровне V8: система модулей, которую написали сами разработчики ноды, как будто живет в другом мире.

[image: Stability: 1 - Expereimental]

В сочетании с ОГРОМНЫМ количеством уже готовых подпрограмм, использующих модули CommonJS, возникает вопрос: Что именно побудило [Ecma International](https://www.ecma-international.org/) принять стандарт, идущий разнонаправленно движению публикации JS-библиотек как пакетов NPM, модулей NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, спецификация модулей ES6 в корень расходится с CommonJS: модули ES6, в отличие от CommonJS, подгружаются асинхронно. Подробнее о особенностях модулей ES6 можно посмотреть в [этой](https://www.slideshare.net/KevinLangleyJr/modern-js-with-es6) презентации

[image: es6-async-modules]

Кроме того, стандарт так же не описывает стандартное местоположение модулей, что порождает "path hell". С этим активно борются разработчики typescript, ситуация подробно описывается [тут](https://goenning.net/2017/07/21/how-to-avoid-relative-path-hell-javascript-typescript-projects/)

```
import { DefaultRenderer } from '../../../rendereders'
import { PayPalClient } from '../../services/PayPal'
```

Странно, что спецификация полностью проигнорировала интересы разработчиков NodeJS, ведь [HTTP/2 Server Push](https://www.slideshare.net/ApacheTrafficServer/http2-server-push) позволяет передать клиенту необходимые скрипты не дожидаясь запроса и задержки в исполнении не будет.

[image: http/2-server-push]

Вероятно, сделано это в уклон отказа от транспиляции по ненадобности и всё большего использования подгрузки кода из сторонних [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) в браузерах. Не приятно лишь то, что крупнейшие корпорации, реализующие CDN сервисы, зарабатывают на таргетинговой рекламе (шпионаже за пользователями).

[image: google-cdn]

P.S. Позже заметил, что за банкет платит именно Google.

[image: Ordinary-Members]